# When is a long line just too long?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

This works (Visual Basic .NET) but seems comically long with all the LINQ to Object methods and in place dimensioning.

```
For Each PNGFile As System.IO.FileInfo In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(".\Archive")).GetFileSystemInfos("*.png", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTimeUTC).Skip(PageSize * Page).Take(PageSize)
    'Do stuff with PNGFile
Next
```

I love that it's all on one line and I think it even reads logically for myself.  But my gut tells me it's readability for the next poor soul having to interpret my code is non-existent.  Or is it?  How do you decide?  Is it worth it to split this line into multiple other dimensioning and assignment statements?  How would you break this particular line up as an example?

I'm new to .NET, but I've been writing code for 10+ years now.  To date, I have determined my maximum line length in code based on the typical resolution I employ when creating the code.  This can't be the best way to decide...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually split lines on a new LINQ extension method, looks cleaner to me:

```
For Each PNGFile As System.IO.FileInfo In New  System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(".\Archive"))
   .GetFileSystemInfos("*.png",System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTimeUTC)
   .Skip(PageSize * Page)
   .Take(PageSize)
      'Do stuff with PNGFile
Next
```

Comment: Yes, now that VB allows you to elide line-continuation characters in most cases, one rarely has an excuse for such long lines.

Comment: @Gabe: I wish I could upvote your comment just for your usage of the word "elide". :)

Comment: Excellent idea, it looks simple, reads intuitively, and avoids creating additional "temporary" variables.  I feel silly I didn't think of doing that myself.

Comment: @Gabe: Even with line-continuation characters, it would still be way more readable than having everything on one line ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I really hate seeing this kind of code... and not just because it's VB ;)

Why don't you split it into several statements? It makes everything easier to read, and it's also easier to debug because you can look at intermediate variables.

Here's how I would write it:

```
Dim archivePath As String = Server.MapPath(".\Archive")
Dim archiveDir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(archivePath)
Dim allFiles = achiveDir.GetFileSystemInfos("*.png", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim filesToDisplay = allFiles.OrderBy(Function(f) f.LastWriteTimeUTC)
                             .Skip(PageSize * Page)
                             .Take(PageSize)

For Each PNGFile As System.IO.FileInfo in filesToDisplay
    'Do stuff with PNGFile
Next
```

IMHO, as soon as you need to think more than 2 seconds to understand a line of code, you can consider it's too long...

Comment: it depends...coming from a functional background you get used to long sequences of functions, even expect it

Comment: What I don't like about this solution is that you end up creating a lot of "temporary" variables.  Not that it really matters from any technical level, but it just seems like extra baggage to me.  I agree it does increase readability though.  But BrokenGlass's solution of simply breaking the entire line up on the method separators is smart.  I see that you do that here also, but I'm still not a fan of the additional variables your approach involves.

Comment: I actually prefer temporary variables over breaking the expression into multiple lines. If the variable names are well-chosen they document the meaning of subexpressions, and also let one debug subexpressions. Performance is likely the same as the JIT will probably have to introduce temporary variables anyway.

Comment: +1, I think the "2 seconds" rule is a good rule. Chaining method calls is not a bad practice (in fact Thomas chained OrderBy, Skip and Take calls here), but many chained methods can hurt readability. In this case it's not too bad, but in some other cases assigning some values to well-named local variables first can help readability a lot, and make debugging easier.

Answer (score 1):

As BrokenGlass said, I would break on the LINQ extensions:

```
  For Each PNGFile As System.IO.FileInfo In New  System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(".\Archive"))
   .GetFileSystemInfos("*.png",System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTimeUTC)
   .Skip(PageSize * Page)
   .Take(PageSize)
      'Do stuff with PNGFile
Next
```

To expand on your next point, how to determine maximum line length: I go by two options. If the code I'm writing is internal, or I know who it's going to, then I set a maximum line length of 120 characters. If the code I'm writing could go global, where I don't know the state of another programmers computer, then I use a maximum line length of 80 characters.

Comment: I like the idea of a specific character count.  Where did you come up with 120 and 80? Doesn't font size and resolution preferences affect these factors to the point it's too hard to predict?

Comment: The original VT100 terminals had a fixed character size, and a display of 80 characters wide - as such, the 80 character maximum has been a sort of standard. You can use it, and not worry about lines being too long anywhere your code is used. For the 120 characters, as widescreen monitors become more and more common, it's started to replace the old 80 character limit. People use 120 because it's more than enough space, and also if your code goes over this limit, it's a good indication you should refactor it :). For font size/resolution, that's really up to the user though.

Answer (score 1):

To take it to a more general level:

I consider (a line of) code formatted properly, when it's "easy on the eye".

In you example I have to scroll too much, so I would split it up in more lines, more or less similar to how BrokenGlass did it.

It's very subjective of course, but in general I prefer to read code by using only my eyes, not by using the keyboard and/or mouse.

Comment: I agree with this concept.  I guess the outstanding question then is: Is it possible to turn the subjective call into a technical one?  Sometimes I spend too much time thinking about code formatting and not enough time coding I think because of the subjective nature of it all.  I'll even sometimes do multiple revisions of the same code before I'll let someone else look at it to ensure it's as readable as possible.  If however there was some "best practice" rule I could employ easily and obviously, it seems like it should save me all that revision time.  Maybe this is just the nature of code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no worse bug then the one you can't see, code that's off the right of the screen edge.  I had some real doozies before discovering that by myself and making a Stone Cold Hard Rule about that.

If you don't have VB 10 yet then you can use space + underscore to break the line:

```
    For Each PNGFile As System.IO.FileInfo _
        In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("mumble") _
           .GetFileSystemInfos("*.foo")
        '' etcetera
    Next
```